# Trying to install HP OfficeJet G85 All-in-One printer software on Windows XP

Tags: printer, java, hp-officejet, jvm

I have been running this printer successfully on a Windows 2000 partition. Because I wanted to use newer fonts available in XP, I decided to try to install the printer software and driver on the Windows XP partition. I have succeeded only in turning the printer into a brick.

I was able to [download the XP printer software](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=30374&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=30374&objectID=bpu01870) from HP. My problems started when the install failed because of a **Java VM problem**, specifically "Unable to start the application, The java virtual machine cannot be loaded". That attempted install disabled the printer.

I found [this very helpful advice](http://hpanswers.blogspot.com/2007/12/unable-to-start-application-java.html) about installing msjavax86.exe. Unfortunately, all of the copies of that that I have found fail with the message " This setup will only upgrade over an **existing version of the Microsoft VM**." I can't seem to find something to download to get that "existing version".

I have J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 4 and Java(TM) 6 Update 23.

Any advice that you can give me about getting the correct Java VM installed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem. what you need to do is uninstall the printer in the control panel than uninstall the j2SE runtime environment. reboot and then install msjavax86.exe , after this  reinstall the printer (make sure the printer is disconnected from the pc before the reboot) .

Comment: Gaaaah! Whatever happened to "Plug and Play"? Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try.